# angular2-datatable throwing error on Import

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I am getting an error when I am importing the statement below in my Angular 2 project.

I am trying to implement pagination in my Angular 2 project and after Googling I found that I need to import the below import statement along with some logic which I need to write.

But I am not sure why the below import statement is throwing error.

I also ran the command

```
npm i -S angular2-datatable
```

Can anyone please explain why the below import is throwing an error?

```
import { TableData } from './table-data'
```

Comment: There isn't any `import` statement in its documentation: https://github.com/mariuszfoltak/angular2-datatable

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/PxBaZs?p=preview

Comment: may be "import { TableData } from 'table-data'"